# How to set ownership on multiple directories in puppet?

Tags: puppet

I have a bunch of directories [ "mydir", "mydir1", "mydir2" , "mydir3" ]. This list will grow eventually.

How can i set the ownership of  directories "mydir*" ?. Will the wildcard * can be used in puppet resource.I am aware of the looping through the array of directories and setting up the permission. Since this list is growing i want to use some wildcard like "mydir*".

Comment: are these files all under the same parent folder if so you could just manage the parent folder.  Also more information on how the list grows may help come up with ideas, of the top of my head i wonder if you could manage the list of dirs in a custom fact

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, Puppet does not support wildcard resource names. There is a good explanation with workarounds at https://ask.puppet.com/question/15769/can-we-use-wild-cards-in-file-resource-path-and-source-parameters/.

The longer answer is no, Puppet does not support wildcard resource names, because the resources are typically enumerated on the Puppet server, which doesn't have access to the client filesystems and so can't run a wildcard to generate matches. As the Puppet answer above says, one option is to use an `exec` resource to set the ownership using a shell glob, something like

```
exec { 'Change owner and group to user.group on /bar/foo*':
  path    => '/bin',
  command => 'chown user.group /bar/foo*',
}
```

Note that the use `exec` resources has problems of its own. In this particularly example, the resource is not idempotent, so will run every time Puppet agent runs, which is not generally acceptable.